# is there any way to clip an appbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to clip two of the appbars corners. I unfortunately can't find anything and I was wondering if there's a work around. Or, possibly if somebody would be kind enough to help me by breaking into Appbar's original code and modifying in some way to clip it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look for the `shapeBorder` option added with https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/21834

```
  const RoundedRectangleBorder roundedRectangleBorder = RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)));

  MaterialApp(
    home: AppBar(
      leading: const Text('L'),
      title: const Text('No Scaffold'),
      shape: roundedRectangleBorder,
      actions: const <Widget>[Text('A1'), Text('A2')],
    ),
  ),
```

It seems this is only available in `master` yet and not shown in the docs.

```
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't want to use `Master channel` & are on `stable channel` - other workaround is using - `ClipRRect`

```
Scaffold(
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    child: AppBar(
                      centerTitle: true,
                      title: Text(title),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: But when you position the green up higher, does it show in the clipped corner area? Mine doesn't which is a problem.

Comment: I just found `Scaffold.extendBodyBehindAppBar` which allows content under the  `Scaffold.appBar`. I only had `Scaffold.extendBody` set to true which does the same for `Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar`.